# Question on the community wikis

Tags: discussion, answers, community-wiki

In one of my question, I decided to post an answer as a [community wiki](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/25569/147) 
The reason as stated in the answer:

> I decided to make a community wiki because all the answers have good
>   points but none covered all the aspects.

It serve as a summary of the different answers posted. I might also add more content to complement it. I was expecting to do the same this with [Creating a realistic world - Spreading religions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25478/creating-a-realistic-world-spreading-religions). I'll try to use the wikis only when it's necessary: when I can't pick an answer as the accepted one because all the answers are good in their own way.

**Is it the best course of action?**

Comment: I feel like this could be used in a lot of places, e.g. most questions with lots of answers.

Comment: I must be missing something. What are you asking here? Or are you merely posting an announcement? You tagged this [discussion], but I see nothing in your question to discuss...

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Everything is in the post except the question mark. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Seems reasonable to me.  Since it's community wiki you're not gaining reputation, and since it's an answer on your own question you won't gain reputation from accepting it, so it strikes me as purely a community service.